# maximum power a number can be raised to with out exceeding y recursion

Tags: c++

i have this program assignment and one part of it is trying to find the max power a number will go to(x) without exceeding a number the user inputs it not to exceed(y). we are using it in a function. this is the whole program and what i have for max power it just keeps returning 0. it is the int maxpower(int x, int y) function i am trying to figure out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// meunue where you can get your options from
void menue() {
    cout << "choose the following options:" << endl;
    cout << "1) Power of x raised by y." << endl;
    cout << "2) Find the max power a number can be raised to." << endl;
    cout << "3) Print out a number with its digits in reversed order." << endl;
    cout << "4) Sum of integers from 1 to n." << endl;
    cout << "5) Product of integers from 1 to n." << endl;
    cout << "6) Quit" << endl;
}

//functions for finding the power usign recursion
int Power(int a, int b) {
    int x = 1, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return Power(a, b--);
        }
        else {
            x = x * a;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int maxpower(int n, int max_value) {
    int temp = temp * n;
    if (temp > max_value)
        return 0;
    else return maxpower(n, max_value + 1);
}

int reverse(int number) {
    int lastDigit, numberOfDigits, sign = 1;//sets the sign equal to one
    // if number is less than 0 returns 0
    if (number < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        //if a number is under 10 than it can not be switched so you times the number     by 10 and switch it.
    if (number < 10)
        return number * sign;

    lastDigit = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    numberOfDigits = log10(number) + 1;
    //recursive statement that calls the function
    return (lastDigit * pow(10, numberOfDigits) + reverse(number)) * sign;
}

//finding the sum
int sum(int n) {
    if (n != 0) {
        return n + sum(n - 1);//recursive statement
    }
    else {
        return n;
    }
}

//finding the product
int product(int n) {
    int temp;
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        temp = n * product(n - 1);
        // recursive statement setting temp == to recursive statement
        return temp;//returning temp
    }

}


int main() {
    int a;
    int x;
    int y;
    int length = 0;
    int temp;
    int results;
    // calls menue and get prints all the options

    do {
        menue();
        //inserts the choice
        cin >> a;

        cout << "you choose:" << a << endl;//prints the choice out.
        //switch statement that will take account for the number you choose and prints    the results
        switch (a) {
            case 1:
                cout << "enter the number to raise" << endl;
                cin >> x;
                cout << " enter the power to raise to: " << endl;
                cin >> y;
                Power(x, y);
                cout << "the result is:" << Power(x, y) << endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cout << "Enter the number to raise:" << endl;
                cin >> x;
                cout << "Enter the number not to exceed:" << endl;
                cin >> y;
                maxpower(x, y);
                cout << "the result is:" << maxpower(x, y) << endl;

                break;

            case 3:
                cout << " enter numbers to be reversed by: " << endl;
                cin >> x;
                temp = x;
                while (temp != 0) {
                    length++;
                    temp = temp / 10;
                }
                reverse(x);
                cout << "the result is:" << reverse(x) << endl;
                break;

            case 4:
                cout << "enter the number to sum to: " << endl;
                cin >> x;
                sum(x);
                cout << "the result is:" << sum(x) << endl;

                break;

            case 5:
                cout << "enter the number to multiply to:" << endl;
                cin >> y;
                product(y);
                cout << "the result is:" << product(y) << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "good bye!!" << endl;
                break;
        }

    } while (a != 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The line "int temp = temp * n;" looks wrong to me.  You're declaring an int named temp (without any value assigned to it).  Then you're saying temp = (uninitialized value) * n.

Comment: int temp = n * n;
   int power = 0;
    if (temp > max_value)
        return 0;                        
  //this is the edited version now it is only printing out 1.    
    else 
    if ( temp < max_value) 
     power++;
     return power;
   return maxpower(n, max_value + 1);

Comment: I attempted to edit the code to match the above comment but I rolled back because the change was not just fixing `int temp = temp * n`

Comment: what would be the the equations for finding the max power a number can be raised to with out exceeding y?

Comment: `int temp = temp * n;` is still wrong.

Comment: okay yeah i just don't even know the equation for finding the maximum power

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to use recursion for this problem. Moreover, recursion is creating a lot of overhead while solving it with a loop works just fine. Do you have to use recursion? If so, then disregard this answer :p. But you'll find below a solution that will work.

Note the `#include <math.h>` bit - you need that to use `pow(base, exponent)`.

Also, `while(true)` is definitely not the best practice, but as long as you have sufficient checks to get out of the loop properly then you're ok. Hence the `max_iteration` and the actual `return` statement that you're looking for.

Best of luck!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int maxpower(int n, int max_value) {
    if ( n > max_value ) return 0;
    int previous, current = 1;
    int max_iteration = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (max_iteration >= 1000) return -1;
        if (pow(n, current) > max_value) {
            return previous;
        }
        previous = current;
        current++;
        max_iteration++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x;
    int y;
    int result;

    std::cout << "Enter the base: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Enter the max number x^pow should not exceed: ";
    std::cin >> y;

    result = maxpower(x, y);

    if (result == -1) {
        std::cout << "Max iteration reached." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << result << " is the maximum power such that " << x << "^" << result << " does not exceed " << y << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As an example of output:

If x = 2 and y = 32, the program will return 5 as the max power (i.e. 2^5 = 32 and is not greater than, but 2^6 > 32).

EDIT:

I realized after I posted that all of your functions are recursive, so perhaps that's a requirement for your assignment. Anyway, below is a recursive solution:

```
int maxpower_rec_helper(int n, int power, int max_value) {
    if (pow(n, power) > max_value) return power - 1;
    return maxpower_rec_helper(n, power + 1, max_value);
}

int maxpower_rec(int n, int max_value) {
    if ( n > max_value ) return 0;
    return maxpower_rec_helper(n, 1, max_value);
}
```

You'll need a helper function to give the initial power `1`, and so as not to disturb your `max_value`.

`return power - 1;` is essentially the same thing as `return previous;` in the iterative example above.